# Questions about affine Weyl group and extended affine Weyl group for SL2.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G=SL_2$. Then the Weyl group is generated by $s_1$. On page 3 of the [lecture notes](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&sqi=2&ved=0CGAQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ms.unimelb.edu.au%2F~degier%2FGandI-Bouwknegt-Notes.pdf&ei=jqnSUpyYKIbOsgaEs4DACQ&usg=AFQjCNHhRgmLTQL-Vkqr2wJOvSAmmg_2YA), it is said that the affine Weyl group is generated by $s_0, s_1$.

(1) The element $s_0s_1$ can be identified with $e^{\alpha}$, the translation over the root $\alpha$.

(2) The extended Weyl group allows translations over integer multiples of the fundamental weight $\frac{1}{2}\alpha$.

I don't understand (1) and (2) very much. Why element $s_0s_1$ can be identified with $e^{\alpha}$? Why the extended Weyl group allows translations over integer multiples of the fundamental weight $\frac{1}{2}\alpha$? Thank you very much.

Comment: The link is broken. In short, $s_1$ should be the reflection at $0$ while $s_0$ should be the reflection at $\frac{1}{2}\alpha$, so the composition can be identified with the translation. Since $SL_2$ is simply connected, the affine Weyl group should be equal to the extended Weyl group (from [Section 11.4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.02329.pdf)). Maybe your definition is different.

Comment: @zxx I had no luck in finding Peter Bouwknegt's "rough write-up of lectures" titled An Introduction to Geometric Representation Theory online, but I did find mentions of them.  One can apparently request the full text from [this researchgate page](https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/Peter-Bouwknegt-5924130), link toward the end of that page.

Comment: Thank you! Now I don't worry too much about the notations. :)